# Square forming challenge

Tags: geometry, dissection

Cut a square into 3 pieces
Rearrange them anyway you want
Cuts must be straight (but can begin/end anywhere).

- Scoring method 1:
  For each visible square 1 point
  For each cut -1 point
- Scoring method 2:
  For each square 1 point
  For each cut -1 point
  [image]

What it the highest score possible? (separate for both scoring methods)

Bonus question: why the point deduction for cuts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer for both methods

> You can cut out two combs. Rotate one by $90°$. Number of squares $O(N^3)$ number of visible squares $O(N^2)$ number of cuts $O(N)$, therefore arbitrarily high score possible in either case.

> [image]
>  [image]

Bonus question:

> Whatever the purpose it clearly failed.

Comment: I missed that one, should have added an extra  constraint that I did not think was needed...